# What value do I need for System.Photo.PeopleNames

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a question. How can I write System.Photo.PeopleNames to a photo?

```
var propertyToSave = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>() { 
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("System.Photo.PeopleNames","???") 
};
await file.Properties.SavePropertiesAsync(propertyToSave);
```

If I try, an exception will be thrown. What value must be used for this property?

Comment: I've tried different things but it seems that UWP does not allow writing `System.Photo.PeopleName` property. Some properties writable, others are not. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca5ac072-8374-4b1c-b592-cd232944b211/what-file-properties-can-be-written-with-storageitemcontentpropertiessavepropertiesasync?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Not all file formats support write "System.Photo.PeopleNames".  Please check [System.Photo.PeopleNames Photo Metadata Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee720019(v=vs.85).aspx) to see if your file is supported. I've tried ".jpg" file successfully.